# Recursively looping over all directories in a given directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that I execute with 2 arguments: a directory and a character ("r", "w" or "x") representing a permission (read, write or execute).

For every .txt file in the given directory, I have to set the permission given as a character. I need to also do this for every .txt file in every sub-directory of the main directory, and the sub-directories of those directories, and so on.
The problem is, my program only sets the permission for the files in the main directory, it's first sub-directory, the first sub-directory of the previous first subdirectory, and so on.

So, for instance if I have the following hierarchy, I have to set the given permission for all the existing files. But my program only sets the permission for the following files:
"File1.txt", "File2.txt", "File3.txt", "File4.txt", "File5.txt". The permission is not set for "File6.txt" and "File7.txt".
[Hierarchy Example Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUqAW.png)

This is the code I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set_mode2.bash

curentDirectory=`pwd`

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
    then
        echo "Wrong number of arguments"
        exit 1
fi
if [ -d "$1" ]
    then continue
        else
            echo "First argument is not a directory"
        exit 2
fi
if [ "$2" = "r" ] || [ "$2" = "w" ] || [ "$2" = "x" ]
    then continue
    else
        echo "Second argument is not a valid permission"
        exit 3
fi


cd $1


for arg in *
do
    if [[ -f $arg ]] && [[ $arg == *.txt ]]
        then
            `chmod +"$2" "$arg"` && echo "Permission $2 added to file $arg"
    fi
done
for arg in *
do
    if [[ -d $arg ]]
        then
            cd "$curentDirectory"
            newDirectory="$1/$arg"
            bash set_mode2.bash "$newDirectory" "$2"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Does anyone know how I can modify the code so that all directories will be accessed and the permission will be set to all the files?
Thank you.

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: `bash`, or `sh`? Pick one or the other, don't tag for both at the same time. There are bash features here that sh doesn't have that could allow an easier answer.

Comment: (also, you're using a lot of constructs here -- like `[[` -- that `sh` doesn't support at all).

Comment: ...and don't use backticks when you don't have a _reason_ to use them. Putting them around your `chmod` command makes your code slower and buggier than it would be without them, f/e.

Comment: Also, see [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), particularly the "Actions in Bulk" and "Complex Actions" sections.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments there are a lot of remarks bout coding style. You  really should use [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) and correct all the remarks you get there.

I will concentrate on the logic-flaw in the program.

```
cd $1
```

Your current directory is now the directory that you gave as an argument, `sub1`.

```
for arg in *
do
    if [[ -f $arg ]] && [[ $arg == *.txt ]]
        then
            `chmod +"$2" "$arg"` && echo "Permission $2 added to file $arg"
    fi
done
I'll leave that, because it is not part of the logic-problem.

We'll use the following directory-structure
```

current                This is where we start the script
__sub1            This is the argument given on the command line
|__subsub1   first sub-directory
|__subsub2   second
___subsub3   and the third

```
for arg in *     # * is subsub1 subsub2  and subsub3
do
    if [[ -d $arg ]]
```

First iteration: `arg` is `subsub1` and we're in `sub1`. This means that the tst is successful.

```
        then
            cd "$curentDirectory"
```

Your current directory is now the directory in which you started the script, i.e `current`.

```
            newDirectory="$1/$arg"
            bash set_mode2.bash "$newDirectory" "$2"
    fi
```

OK. Next iteration.

```
for arg in *     # * is subsub1 subsub2  and subsub3
do
    if [[ -d $arg ]]
```

Second iteration: `arg` is `subsub2`, and we're in `current`. There is no directory `current/subsub2`, so the test fails.

Third iteration: `arg` is `subsub3`, and we're in `current`. There is no directory `current/subsub3`, so the test fails.

So that is why it works only on the first directory and not for the rest.